# Writing to objects

Tags: java, object, serialization

I am trying to figure out how to write(serialize?) to objects. 
If I have this code here:

```
   public class TestObject {

private String words;

public void getWords(){

    words = "These are some important words.";

    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file.txt");

        pw.println(words);

        System.out.println(words);

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }       
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    TestObject to = new TestObject();   
    to.getWords();
}
```

And wanted to write the words from String "words" to an object how would I do that?
And why is writing to objects useful?

Comment: What you describe is not serialization, FYI.

Comment: You've just written a string to file. It's not object serialization. Object serialization, you would use ObjectOutputStream with underlying FileOutputStream to serialize to a file. Object serialization allows convenient data communication between 2 network entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your class will need to implement the serializable interface. Then any variable that is not marked as transient is able to be serialised. That is as long as it is serialisable itself. String is but if you had another variable with a type of your own you would need to make that serialiseable also or mark it transient.

It is useful so that you can transmit your objects over a network as in a recent app I built that includes a web site and an application that both use the same database. In this case the application is running in a different jvm and can accept and construct an object sent to it from the server.

Comment: One thing to realize when sending objects from server to clients, if you serialize only JDK class types, it'll work in the client side with little effort. However, if you serialize your own objects, the client needs your class definition for it to work. Imagine if you have many different clients connecting to your server, this would not be ideal.